# Cro: How to define port for each services in .cro.yml?

Tags: raku, cro

After creating stub services with *cro stub http test test*, I have defined TEST_PORT environment variable in **.cro.yml**:

```
---
id: test
cro: 1
name: "test"
endpoints: 
  - 
    id: http
    name: HTTP
    protocol: http
    host-env: TEST_HOST
    port-env: TEST_PORT
links:  []
entrypoint: service.p6
env:
  - name: TEST_PORT
    value: "3001"
...
```

Nevertheless, Cro still uses the default 20000 port. [Alex Schroeder](https://alexschroeder.ch/wiki/2018-10-08_Setting_up_Oddmuse_6) exports the environment variables to start Cro in a different port. The command "*export TEST_PORT="3001" && cro run*" still uses the default port.

What would be the right form of defining the service port in Cro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `cro run` tool automatically assigns ports to all services that it starts. This is to ensure they get a free port that isn't in use for something else. Thus, it will inject environment variables with the ports it has chosen. You don't get to choose the port when using `cro run`.

To run the service on chosen ports, do it without `cro run`, that is, just export the environment variables and invoke the service like `raku -Ilib service.p6` (or with `perl6 -Ilib service.p6` if you have an older installation). That way, the service will see the environment variable containing your choice of port. The default `Dockerfile` is set up to do this also.

Note that the `cro` development tool is intended solely as a *development time* aid, and is not suitable for a production deployment (which is the primary case where picking the port would matter).